# Product of even sum of list of lists Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this exercise : show the product of even sums from a list of lists ( the even sum of every list)

```hs
sumaNumerePareLinie :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumaNumerePareLinie [] = 0
sumaNumerePareLinie (x : xs)
  | even x = x + sumaNumerePareLinie xs
  | otherwise = sumaNumerePareLinie xs 
   --this function determines the sum of the even numbers in a line

produsSume :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
produsSume [] = 1
produsSume (x : xs)
  | x = sumaNumerePareLinie x * produsSume xs
  | otherwise = produsSume xs
```

I don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: dou you get any compiler/runtime errors? what exactly is *product of even sums from a list of lists*? (I don't get the *even sums* part - don't know what this is)

Comment: my best guess: `product . map (sum . filter even)` should do it or be really similar (that is the product of the sums of all even numbers)

Comment: Also: what do you need to *show*? Show sounds like you should prove something - so are you supposed to write the function or show that this function does it?

Comment: if i have this example [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4]] it will do 6 * 6= 36

Comment: ok the expression I gave you does exactly this

Comment: BTW: your `produsSume` does not work becuase `| ...` <- is a *guard*  and the guard needs first an expression of type `Bool` and then a `=` and then an expression that is supposed to be returned if the condition for the guard holds - you did this right in all instances but the first one of `produsSume (x:xs)` - note that `otherwise` is defined as just `otherwise = True`

Comment: So, you sum only the even values in each sublist, the multiply the resulting products? So `(2 + 4) * (2 + 4)`? "Even sum" implies you are summing the *entire* sublist, then including it in the product if that sum itself is even (a sum that is even, not the sum of even values).

Answer (score 3):

Your `produsSume` is wrong

this should fix it:

```hs
produsSume :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
produsSume [] = 1
produsSume (x : xs) = sumaNumerePareLine x * produsSume xs
```

Note that there is already a prelude-function for calculating the *product of a list of numbers* [`product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:product) - so:

```hs
produsSume = product
```

There is also [`sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) and I hope you know `filter` and `map`. So you can write this as just:

```hs
produsSume :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
produsSume xs = product . map (sum (filter even xs))
```

or a bit more compressed in *point-free style*:

```hs
produsSume :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
produsSume = product . map (sum . filter even)
```